# How can I save models with unique names?

Tags: python, keras, model, save

I am making multiple LSTM models with different parameters and want to save them with unique and recognizable names but I am getting an error. I have tried everything "Google" told me to but nothing worked. Probably I am writing the file name incorrectly but I am new to python and i could not fix it myself.

```
seq_lens = [4,5,6,7] dropout_rates = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5] num_hl
= [1,2,3,4] node_hl = [10, 15, 20, 25] learning_rates = [0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001]

for current_seq_len in seq_lens:
    for current_drop_rate in dropout_rates:
        for current_number_hls in num_hl:
            for current_node_hls in node_hl:
                for current_learning_rate in learning_rates:

                    current_name_model = "seq_len:" + str(current_seq_len) + "_" + "dr_rate:" + str(current_drop_rate) + "_"
+ "num_hl:" + str(current_number_hls) + "_" + "node_hl:" + str( current_node_hls) + "_" + "learn_rt:" + str(current_learning_rate)

                    X_train, y_train = create_data(train_dataset, current_seq_len) 

                    layers_size = [1]
                    for hl in range(3): # +1 because first layer is input layer, not hidden layer
                        layers_size.extend([current_seq_len])
                    layers_size.extend([1])

                    model = Sequential()
                    model.add(LSTM(input_shape=((X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])),units=layers_size[1], return_sequences=True))
                    model.add(Dropout(current_drop_rate))
                    # hidden layers
                    for hl in range(current_number_hls+1): # +1 because first layer is input layer, not hidden layer
                        model.add(LSTM(layers_size[hl+1], return_sequences=True, input_shape=((X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))))
                        model.add(Dropout(current_drop_rate))
                     # output layer
                    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=layers_size[-1])))
                    model.add(AveragePooling1D())
                    model.add(Flatten())                
                    model.add(Dense(units = 1,activation='sigmoid'))
                    opt = Adam(lr=current_learning_rate) 
                    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt)
                    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=200, validation_split=0.1, verbose = False)
                    makedirs('models')
                    filename = 'models/model_' + current_name_model + '.h5'
                    model.save(filename)
                    print('>Saved %s' % filename)
```

I am getting this error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-74935647b8eb> in <module>
     47                     # save model
     48                     filename = 'models/model_' + current_name_model + '.h5'
---> 49                     model.save(filename)
     50                     print('>Saved %s' % filename)
     51                     #!mkdir -p saved_model

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1088             raise NotImplementedError
   1089         from ..models import save_model
-> 1090         save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1091 
   1092     def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
    377         opened_new_file = False
    378 
--> 379     f = h5dict(filepath, mode='w')
    380 
    381     try:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py in __init__(self, path, mode)
    184             self._is_file = False
    185         elif isinstance(path, str):
--> 186             self.data = h5py.File(path, mode=mode)
    187             self._is_file = True
    188         elif isinstance(path, dict):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in __init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0, track_order, **kwds)
    406                 fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size,
    407                                fapl, fcpl=make_fcpl(track_order=track_order),
--> 408                                swmr=swmr)
    409 
    410             if isinstance(libver, tuple):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    177         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
    178     elif mode == 'w':
--> 179         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_TRUNC, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
    180     elif mode == 'a':
    181         # Open in append mode (read/write).

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.create()

OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'models/model_seq_len:4_dr_rate:0.1_num_hl:1_node_hl:10_learn_rt:0.01.h5', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using colons in your file name which might not be allowed (not allowed in windows, not sure about ubuntu). Also add a './' before your filename.

Comment: Thank you! i removed colons and it solved the problem

Comment: @AnanoBasilaia Welcome to SO! If this answer solved your problem please mark it as correct, thanks!